# How to create a class that implements mouseListener

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I want to create a class that implement mouseListener interface (this class will override all mouseListener methods) instead of override all the methods in the main class. When I tring to do so I get an error.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game {


    public Game(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game app = new Game();
    } 
}
```

MyMouseListener code:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;



public class MyMouseListener implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }


}
```

**edit:** I understand my problem was that I implement keyListener insteed of mouseListener in the class MyMouseListener so I changed this and MyMouseListener code is now:

```
public class MyMouseListener extends Game implements MouseListener{



    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }


}
```

Comment: Well... Your class implements `keyListener` not `MouseListener`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you might be having is the frame not showing up, this is because you did not tell it to show the frame, use the following method:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

In addition as stated by Jorn Vernee, in your class MyMouseListener you have to implement the MouseListener interface instead of the KeyListener.

I tried this code out and it worked just fine:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public Game(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game app = new Game();
    } 
}
```

Code for MyMouseListener:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("clicked");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Also consider [`MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), and see [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I tried this and its just open up a lot of JFrames and i dont know why